# Retaining row names when converting matrix to a factor value

Tags: r, matrix

This most likely has a simple remedy, but I'm trying to convert a matrix with one column and row names to a factor value, but when I do so the row names disappear:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
y <- c(1, 0, 1, 0)
y <- as.matrix(y)
rownames(y) <- x

f <- as.factor(y[,1])
```

So then the factor 'f' looks like:

```
    [,1]
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
```

Rather than:

```
    [,1]
A    1
B    0
C    1
D    0
```

Does anyone know if there's a way of retaining the row names when having coverting to a factor value?

Comment: Did you meant `f <- factor(y[,1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have any other option than to

```
f <- as.factor(y)
dim(f) <- c(4, 1)
rownames(f) <- rownames(y)
f
#   [,1]
# A 2   
# B 1   
# C 2   
# D 1   
# Levels: 1 2
```

Matrices aren't really well suited for factors, a data frame would be a better option.